# How to evaluate limits?

Tags: limits

I am stuck on this question and am not sure how to evaluate it.

> $$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}}{x-2}$$

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\frac1x-\frac12}{x-2}$? If so, the first step is probably to make it simpler, like getting rid of the fractions in the numerator.

Comment: yeah that is what i meant arthur, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By definition,

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{1/x-1/2}{x-2}$$

is the derivative of $1/x$ at $2.$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{2}=-\frac {x-2}{2x} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ x } -\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }{ x-2 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac { \frac { 2-x }{ 2x }  }{ x-2 }  } =-\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac { 1 }{ 2x } =-\frac { 1 }{ 4 }  } $$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) is very effective here.
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{d}{dx}(x-2)}=\cdots$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Why use L'Hopital. The defintion of the derivative shows the answer is $(1/x)'(2).$

Comment: @zhw. Oh yes, you are right. Well spotted.

Comment: @zhw. You may want to add that as an answer if you like (I won't steal it since it was your idea).